# Как сохранять состояние popup расширения Chrome?

Tags: chrome-extension

При закрытии popup.html не приходит ни сообщение onunload, ни сообщение onbeforeunload. Когда сохранять состояние расширения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант первый.
Сохранять состояние расширения при любом изменении оного, например, по нажатию кнопки, щелчку мышью и пр.

Вариант второй.
Кроме popup.html иметь и background.html в составе расширения. Все данные, определяющие состояние расширения хранить в background и сохранять уже его по onunload.